# BuildConfig.java is not configuring properly in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, buildconfig

When I run my flutter project, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Sourav Kannantha B\Documents\AndroidProjects\ecommercestore\build\app\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\skbsmk\ecommercestore\BuildConfig.java:14: error: illegal escape character
  public static final String fluttersdk = "C:\Users\Sourav Kannantha B\Documents\Flutter";
                                              ^
.
.
.
```

I can see why that is error, because `BuildConfig.java` contains this line:

```
public static final String fluttersdk = "C:\Users\Sourav Kannantha B\Documents\Flutter";
```

But my `local.properties` file contains the path in correct format:

```
flutter.sdk=C:\\Users\\Sourav Kannantha B\\Documents\\Flutter
```

I don't know why, while building it is skipping one backslash. I even tried to edit `local.properties` to this:

```
flutter.sdk=C:\\\\Users\\\\Sourav Kannantha B\\\\Documents\\\\Flutter
```

and this:

```
flutter.sdk=C:/Users/Sourav Kannantha B/Documents/Flutter
```

But as soon as I run the project, android studio is automatically changing these to as it was before.

**EDIT**: Project was running properly before. This all started when I added `com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin` to my android gradle file. But I'm not sure if this has to do anything with this error.

**EDIT**: My bad, error was indeed related to `com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin`. After removing that, error got resolved. Can someone explain this behaviour.

Comment: I opened only android part of the app in android studio, and edited the `local.properties` file. The app is running properly. So I guess the problem is in `Flutter` plugin.

Comment: I am having the same problem. any updates on this? Did you use other method to hide secret keys?

Comment: @KyooSikLee See my latest answer below for how I am currently hiding my keys. You may also see another answer below by Valentin which provides a solution to use secrets plugin. If you follow Valentin's solution, tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had more or less same issue. The autogenerated `buildConfig` file was not correct in where it added some other declaration.

```
/**
* Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
*/
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.package";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "release";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "staging";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0";

  // Added this weird declaration
  public static final String  = ;
  public static final String sdkdir = " C :  U s e r s  A d m i n i s t r a t o r  A p p D a t a  L o c a l  A n d r o i d  S d k " ";
}
```

Removing `com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me, helps flutter's relocation. When my path contains any folder name starts with big letter I had that error. When I relocated flutter to new folder and path changed, problem disappeared.

Before my path looked like:
`C:\Users\Kate\flutter`
Users and Kate generates problem

After relocation:
`C:\tools\flutter`

After relocation remember to changed your Flutter SDK path in settings (File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter if you use AndroidStudio) and your Dart SDK path. Then restart IDE.

After that I had to use `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get` to clean and restore dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue on Windows since I added the secrets plugin. I found in the documentation that you can move your secrets into a specific properties file which the plugin can use. That way, you can leave the **local.properties** file unmodified.

See point 8 in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin). In a nutshell, you need to add the following code in your app's **build.gradle** :

```
secrets {
    propertiesFileName = "secrets.properties"
}
```

And in secrets.properties, put your secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Currently now, I'm hiding my Maps API key as below:

Storing the api key in `local.properties`

```
MAPS_API_KEY=<MY_API_KEY>
```

Declaring the api key placeholder in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

Replacing the api key placeholder in module level `build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
def mapsApiKey = localProperties.getProperty('MAPS_API_KEY')
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders += [MAPS_API_KEY: mapsApiKey]
    }
}
```